# Dealing with sibling surprise?

Tags: autosomal-dna

My Husband's DNA through Ancestry.com shows his first match at 1922cm's over 45 segments. This person has a small tree (750 names) going back about 4 generations. My husband also matches 5 other people in this persons father's family... 3 first cousins and 2 nephews. The problem is this family is completely unknown to us and in talking to the match family/cousins we can find no connection. With that high of a cm match we concluded the match and my husband must be 1/2 brothers as they are within 10 years of the same age, so that rules out grandparents and nieces/nephews as my husband is the oldest of his known siblings. Sadly the match person passed away just months before I made contact with the family. At first I thought the issue to be on my husbands side, as in his father was not who he had believed.. in the past few days I have discovered matches through both lines on my husbands fathers side so now it looks like the issue was with the matches parents. Because of the sketchy information on the other side, and the fact that the match person has just passed away and the family is dealing with that, I just don't know how to proceed. I'd like to document this line if it is truly a sibling even though he has passed away.

Can someone suggest how to proceed?

Comment: This may be more of a interpersonal situation then a genealogical one. I think your best bet may be just to wait until the survivors are ready to discuss it, if ever.

Comment: It's likely that at some point, someone in the other family will submit an genealogy DNA sample, and notice some of the same things you did. That happened in my family, where two close female relatives who were believed to be sisters turned out to be half-sisters.  Their children have elected not to tell them, believing that the news that their mother cheated on their father served no useful purpose.  In your case, if the recently-deceased half-brother has siblings, they also might not welcome such news. Once someone in their family takes in interest, though, the dynamic may change.